# PHP array_push adds unnecessary quotes

Tags: php, json, array-push

So I need to add data to my JSON as they are.

> expected JSON

```
  "users": [
    {
      "username": "admin",
      "password": "admin",
      "isAdmin": true
    },
    {
      "username": "bleh",
      "password": "meh",
      "isAdmin": false
    }
  ]
```

> instead I get:

```
"users": [
        {
          "username": "admin",
          "password": "admin",
          "isAdmin": true
        },
        {
          "username": "bleh",
          "password": "meh",
          "isAdmin": false
        },
 "{\"isAdmin\":false,\"username\":\"test1\",\"password\":\"$2y$10$fSb.0bw\\\/MbtBx.PHerRdU.gahYnRezZZuy8VYL41ah8YwPxW6hOTq\"}"
          ]
```

I am losing my mind over this issue as I can't find the way to find what part of my code adds the extra quotes and backslashes to the added string.

This is my php code, that takes care of adding values to JSON:

```
      if (self::checkExistence($this->username) == true){
        return false;
    }

    $newUserJson = json_encode($this);

    $inp = file_get_contents(getcwd() . self::USERS_LOCATION);
    $tempArray = json_decode($inp,true);

    array_push($tempArray["users"], $newUserJson);

    $jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
    file_put_contents(getcwd() . self::USERS_LOCATION, $jsonData);

    return true;
```

I am aware of the fact that using a file instead of a database is not "best practice", but using a file is enough for my needs right now, so please don't comment thing like "use db instead".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are double encoding your string. You encode it once `$newUserJson`, then you insert it into an array `$tempArray["users"]` and encode that array.

You can remove this line:

`$newUserJson = json_encode($this);`

and then update this line

`array_push($tempArray["users"], $this);`

and that should fix the issues

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
$newUserJson = json_encode($this);
```

with the following line:

```
$newUserJson = $this;
```